# Can helm-apropos display the key bindings for commands the way helm-M-x does?

Tags: key-bindings, helm, commands

I'm a recent convert to helm. helm-M-x displays commands and includes key-bindings in parens after the command name. helm-apropos displays commands and other things. I'd like it to display the key bindings for commands that have them the same way as helm-M-x does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to helm, you will like it ;)

One way to do it is to just overwrite the original function which builds the source for the apropos command candidates with this:

```
(defun helm-def-source--emacs-commands (&optional default)
  (helm-build-in-buffer-source "Commands"
    :init `(lambda ()
             (helm-apropos-init 'commandp ,default))
    :fuzzy-match helm-apropos-fuzzy-match
    :filtered-candidate-transformer (and (null helm-apropos-fuzzy-match)
                                         'helm-apropos-default-sort-fn)

    :candidate-transformer 'helm-M-x-transformer-1
    :nomark t
    :action '(("Describe Function" . helm-describe-function)
              ("Find Function" . helm-find-function)
              ("Info lookup" . helm-info-lookup-symbol))))
```

The added part is this:

```
:candidate-transformer 'helm-M-x-transformer-1
```

which adds the keybindings to the candidates list. Just load this function after you loaded helm in your init file.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something like that but wasn't sure of which function to modify, the format to add the transformer (other places use               :fc-transformer) or if helm-M-x-transformer-1 was exactly right (if all it does is add the keybinding it seems like it could have a better name).

Comment: @hatschipuh, how come I get a (wrong-type-argument listp helm-M-x-transformer-1) error?

Comment: @EmacsUser I don't know, somehow at your side it seems that it is expecting helm-M-x-transformer-1 to be a list of functions? Try to use `:candidate-transformer '(helm-M-x-transformer-1)` instead.

Comment: Not work for me, no key bindings in the list of `helm-apropos` like `helm-M-x`

Comment: [It was decided in 2015 that this functionality will not be implemented due to performance considerations.](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1140) In the same thread, I achieve the same using advice instead of redefining the function, which has maintenance implications.

Comment: Also note that `helm-M-x-transformer-1` requires `(require 'helm-command)`.